# Grouped Bar Chart with grouping in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to create a grouped bar chart in plotly, but I cannot seem to color my bars within a group(so they are all the same color). Does anyone know how to do this in plotly? I would like to color my barchart according to the SubCategory(so all bars in a sub-category have their own color). I have tried adding traces to a graph, but no luck. Thanks.

```
sample <- data.frame(
  Category <- c("Furniture","Furniture","Furniture","Furniture",
                "Office Supplies","Office Supplies", "Office Supplies", "Office Supplies",
                "Office Supplies", "Office Supplies", "Office Supplies", "Office Supplies",
                "Office Supplies", "Technology","Technology","Technology","Technology"),
  SubCategory <- c("Bookcases","Chairs","Furnishings","Tables","Appliances","Art","Binders","Envelopes", 
                   "Fasteners","Labels","Paper","Storage",  "Supplies", "Accessories","Copiers","Machines",
                   "Phones"),
  sales <- c(889222.51,920892.65,239840.16,445823.93,614737.91,225594.68,281494.68,104903.88,50156.06,44269.30,
             150113.36,692903.08,152196.19,463383.33,965899.78,458655.43,1005525.38)
)

#plot code so far
sample %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = Category,
    y = sales,
    type = "bar",
    group = SubCategory
  )
```

Below is what I have so far, but the coloring is not based on the grouping. When I supply a color variable, it does not color all the bars within the SubCategory the same color. Is this is possible bug?
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the above graph with your original data and code...

Comment: Sorry, there were a few naming bugs in the code. Should be fixed now

Comment: your new code does not produce the above graph still....

Comment: what version of plotly are you using? I'm using 3.6.0. I just ran the code in my r session, and it worked fine. I just made the edits after I posted my answer, so try it again, and see if you still have issues reproducing the graph.

Comment: You're on a very old version of ``plotly``. You'll have to update to the newest one if you want help from others (``plotly_4.1.0 ``). Until you can provide a reproducible example, it's tough to help you. Your current example creates the thick blue bars and thats it.

Comment: Cyrus, the example I shared is reproducible with the CRAN version of plotly. I don't have access to the dev version 4.1.0 in my current environment. If you know how to solve this in the dev version, then by all means I'm all ears.

Comment: I just installed 3.6.0 and I still cant replicate your code. You need to clear your workspace and run it again. I've run it on two different versions of plotly in  rstudio, in normal r environment, and in terminal, all the same result. Also make sure to use the exact replicate data you supplied using the same code to create it.

Comment: Can you provide the error your are receiving? I just cleared my workspace, and I am able to run the code just fine. Here is my sessioninfo> session_info()
Session info ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
 system   x86_64, darwin13.4.0        
 ui       RStudio (0.99.1292)         
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       America/Chicago             
 date     2016-08-27

Comment: Not sure, but I renamed the columns and it works, does your final solution absolutely need to be in plotly, or is ggplot acceptable?

Comment: Yeah my changes to the code were renaming the variables, so I'd guess that you maybe forget to update your code with my new code posted? I'd like to stick with plotly as I think the syntax is a little more readable, and this chart is supposed to be interactive, but I'd definetly look at ggplot2 code as well.

Comment: gotcha, I got a solution for ``ggplot2`` but I'm searching one for ``plotly`` right now, unfortunately ``ggplotly()`` isn't returning a similar output to ``ggplot``

Comment: yeah I'm wondering if this is a bug in 3.6.0. I know the dev version of plotly has some major changes to the code, but last time I tried I just had issues installing it. let me try the dev version of plotly and see if i still get issues.

Comment: I have a solution using ``ggplotly()`` actually but there are spaces between the bars for ``furniture`` and ``technology`` because they don't have as many subcategories as ``office supplies``.

Comment: dev and this version seem to be acting identical in this situation

Comment: hmm...I tried posting a bug earlier this week, and was told to go to the plotly communitty, but no one responded on..see: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/695

Comment: the approach mentioned there did not work either, which seems pretty tedious for what I am trying to create.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `ggplot2`....

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot) #ggplot2 white theme 

sample <- data.frame(
  Category <- c("Furniture","Furniture","Furniture","Furniture",
                "Office Supplies","Office Supplies", "Office Supplies", "Office Supplies",
                "Office Supplies", "Office Supplies", "Office Supplies", "Office Supplies",
                "Office Supplies", "Technology","Technology","Technology","Technology"),
  SubCategory <- c("Bookcases","Chairs","Furnishings","Tables","Appliances","Art","Binders","Envelopes", 
                   "Fasteners","Labels","Paper","Storage",  "Supplies", "Accessories","Copiers","Machines",
                   "Phones"),
  sales <- c(889222.51,920892.65,239840.16,445823.93,614737.91,225594.68,281494.68,104903.88,50156.06,44269.30,
             150113.36,692903.08,152196.19,463383.33,965899.78,458655.43,1005525.38)
)

colnames(sample)<-c("category","subcategory","Sales")

ggplot(sample, aes(category, Sales)) +   
  geom_bar(aes(fill = category, color = subcategory), position = "dodge", stat = "identity")+scale_color_manual(values = c(rep("white", 17)))+theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Now using `plotly` 's `ggplotly`

```
plot<-ggplot(sample, aes(category, Sales)) +   
      geom_bar(aes(fill = category, color=subcategory), position = "dodge", stat="identity")+scale_color_manual(values=c(rep("white", 17)))+theme(legend.position="none")
ggplotly(plot)
```

[image]

Finally, using original `plotly`

```
sample <- data.frame(
  Category <- c("Furniture","Furniture","Furniture","Furniture",
                "Office Supplies","Office Supplies", "Office Supplies", "Office Supplies",
                "Office Supplies", "Office Supplies", "Office Supplies", "Office Supplies",
                "Office Supplies", "Technology","Technology","Technology","Technology"),
  SubCategory <- c("Bookcases","Chairs","Furnishings","Tables","Appliances","Art","Binders","Envelopes", 
                   "Fasteners","Labels","Paper","Storage",  "Supplies", "Accessories","Copiers","Machines",
                   "Phones"),
  sales <- c(889222.51,920892.65,239840.16,445823.93,614737.91,225594.68,281494.68,104903.88,50156.06,44269.30,
             150113.36,692903.08,152196.19,463383.33,965899.78,458655.43,1005525.38)
)

sample %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = SubCategory,
    y = sales,
    type = "bar",
    group = Category
)
```

[image]

Comment: Very comprehensive, thanks for your help with this. Did you use 3.6.0 for these? Do you think the ggplotly may have a bug with the spacing? I've been told that you are supposed to use traces for each bar, but that just seems really crazy to be honest. Thoughts?

Comment: no problem! Glad I could help. I created it using 3.6.0 but I just checked and it works on the development version as well. Yeah I saw that use of traces from that link you sent. Seems awfully tedious. There might be a better work around for the spacing -I don't think its necessarily a bug. The spacing occurs bc there are different levels for each category (one has 3, another 4, and another has 8). It would be nice if they added a feature where you could control how the ggploty() output deals with spaces -perhaps a good feature request to submit to plotly's github.

Comment: Good point. Do you think my original plotly code is supposed to work similar with the output from your ggplot code? When I read the documentation, that's what I imagine, but it seems like the more parameters I put in the code, it just messes it up even more.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not quite sure, I've only recently started to dabble with plotly. the thing with plotly is that it translates R code into d3.js and then displays. This is specially true of ``ggplotly`` -so it has that "hiccup" issue with translating weird things like how to handle spaces

Comment: Very true. I wonder if that is an issue too. I guess if I specify to group a variable, I would expect to see it, as in your ggplot graph, so I wonder if it has something to do with d3.js. Even some of the examples on modern data are extremely complicated, and really don't help explain the basic functionality.http://moderndata.plot.ly/time-series-charts-by-the-economist-in-r-using-plotly/

Comment: I really wonder if the bars are supposed to be limited by errors with RColorBrewer. I was getting this error earlier: Warning message:
In RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(N, "Set2") :
  n too large, allowed maximum for palette Set2 is 8
Returning the palette you asked for with that many colors

Comment: well thats not an error its just a warning letting you know its not spitting out anything unforeseen , its just letting you know RColorBrewer's palettes have a maximum of 8 classes, which they do or sometimes its 9 not sure, so somewhere in your code you were trying to map using a single color palette that was being assigned more than 8 classes. so the warning was letting you know its only mapping up to its max class set. see http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=sequential&scheme=BuGn&n=8 for R's color brewer ----I think...

Comment: interesting.....i'd love to see some examples plotly being used in business intelligence automation with R, as I think it could really shine, but with something like this, it just seems very small.

Comment: If you are interested in more interactivity(in the browser), RCloud does have some pretty impressive graphics that definitely compete with plotly.....you can run their docker container using kitematic http://rcloud.social/gallery/index.html

Comment: Just a note: for someone looking for an only-`plotly` version, the argument `group` results now deprecated

Comment: For some reason I had to add ~ to x, y, and type values, as plotly couldn't detect them itself.

```R
sample %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~SubCategory,
    y = ~sales,
    type = "bar",
    group = ~Category
)
```

Answer (score 1):

While I understand that the question asks for a `plotly` solution, I would like to put forth a perfectly simple solution in my go-to package (and for quite a few others I'm certain) for charting - `ggplot2` !

```
library(ggplot2)

sample <- data.frame(
  Category = c("Furniture","Furniture","Furniture","Furniture",
                "Office Supplies","Office Supplies", "Office Supplies", "Office Supplies",
                "Office Supplies", "Office Supplies", "Office Supplies", "Office Supplies",
                "Office Supplies", "Technology","Technology","Technology","Technology"),
  SubCategory = c("Bookcases","Chairs","Furnishings","Tables","Appliances","Art","Binders","Envelopes", 
                   "Fasteners","Labels","Paper","Storage",  "Supplies", "Accessories","Copiers","Machines",
                   "Phones"),
  sales = c(889222.51,920892.65,239840.16,445823.93,614737.91,225594.68,281494.68,104903.88,50156.06,44269.30,
             150113.36,692903.08,152196.19,463383.33,965899.78,458655.43,1005525.38)
)

ggplot(sample,aes(x=Category,y=sales)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.5, position="dodge", aes(fill=SubCategory),
       color="black")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I just realized I requested the wrong type of chart...updated my question

Comment: So, would a non stacked version of this above chart be fine? Or would you insist on plotly? :-)

Comment: Sure, go for it. I'd like to see if it is even possible using plotly, as I think the syntax is cleaner, but I'm open to what the ggplot code would look like.

Comment: Close, except each subcategory is colored differently. so all the subcategories in furniture should be blue, and office supplies green, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on @petergensler's very comprehensive answer, to date `group` is deprecated in plotly. Plotly now prefers users to use plotly::group_by(), which is straightforward enough:

```
sample <- data.frame(
  Category <- c("Furniture","Furniture","Furniture","Furniture",
                "Office Supplies","Office Supplies", "Office Supplies", "Office Supplies",
                "Office Supplies", "Office Supplies", "Office Supplies", "Office Supplies",
                "Office Supplies", "Technology","Technology","Technology","Technology"),
  SubCategory <- c("Bookcases","Chairs","Furnishings","Tables","Appliances","Art","Binders","Envelopes", 
                   "Fasteners","Labels","Paper","Storage",  "Supplies", "Accessories","Copiers","Machines",
                   "Phones"),
  sales <- c(889222.51,920892.65,239840.16,445823.93,614737.91,225594.68,281494.68,104903.88,50156.06,44269.30,
             150113.36,692903.08,152196.19,463383.33,965899.78,458655.43,1005525.38)
)

sample %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = SubCategory,
    y = sales,
    type = "bar"
    ) %>% 
      plotly::group_by(Category)
```

Note that plotly's group_by() can cause some frustrating package problems with the way more popular dplyr::group_by(), so good to be specific.